# Spark StructField.dataType throws NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Client.scala:

```
...
import Implicits._

val singersDF = Seq(
  ("beatles", "help|hey jude"),
  ("romeo", "eres mia")
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

val actualDF = singersDF.withColumn(
  "hit_songs",
  split(col("hit_songs"), "\\|")
)

actualDF.foo()
...
```

Implicits.scala:

```
...
object Implicits {
  implicit class Implicits(df: DataFrame) extends java.io.Serializable {
    def foo () = {
      df.foreachPartition((partition: Iterator[Row]) => {
        partition.foreach((row: Row) => {
          val types = df.schema.fields.map(_.dataType)
...
```

The last line throws:

```
20/04/15 18:18:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.schema(Dataset.scala:465)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `schema` val for your implicit class:

```
implicit class Implicits(df: DataFrame) extends java.io.Serializable {
  val schema: StructType = df.schema
  def foo(): Unit = {
    df.foreachPartition {
      (partition: Iterator[Row]) =>
        partition.foreach {
          row: Row =>
            val types = schema.fields.map(_.dataType)
            // ...
        }
        partition
    }
  }
}
```

I think NPE in your example is because `foreachPartition` in `DataFrame` can't know something about DataFrame structure and this abstraction *"disappeared"* when you starts process functions passed to `foreach`.